# Different css on production and XAMPP

Tags: php, css, sass, gulp

I have `app.css` file in `/public/css/app/css` and the following link in the head:

`<link rel="stylesheet" href="\css\app.css">`

In XAMPP it works perfectly but when I deploy on production changes are not displayed - https://i.stack.imgur.com/c3MZP.png. I checked the deployement and it works as well.

Is it possible that it is due to the fact that in fact href points to `/source/app.**s**ccs` - https://i.stack.imgur.com/CeXS9.png? But it does the same both on production and XAMPP.

I have gulp.js and node.js installed, but don't use them.

So I have 2 questions:
1. Why information is not displayed the same way on XAMPP and production?
2. What generates /source/app.scss?

Comment: Do you have any cache on the production server? Try CTRL+F5.

Comment: I have suspicion you are using Boostrap or Foundation? Those use scss files and then compile them to css using gulp or compass. How are you deploying to prod?

Comment: @Jerodev Thank you, that help)

Answer (score 1):

Change this `<link...>` pathing to use Unix `/` and not DOS `\'

```
<link rel="stylesheet" href="/css/app.css">
```

The same goes for all pathing info in PHP and Apache.

The `/` will also work on windows Apache/PHP as they both fix a / on windows to whatever it should be.

Developing on Windows and running on UNIX is no hassle, but you have to rememeber a few simple rules and this is one of them.

Answer (score -1):

A potential solution would be that you're trying to evaluate raw scss instead of the compiled css. If you have a javascript sass compiler on your local version but not on your production, it could explain the issues you're having.

`Scss` is a raw, not compiled form of CSS built with Sass.
As it is not valid CSS, your browser can't interpret it correctly, it needs to be compiled to do so.

Try pasting the scss to http://www.sassmeister.com, make a `.css` file with the compiled output and update your `<link>` to point at the `.css` file.